# Monitor if Kafka is up?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I need to simply monitor if my Kafka cluster is up. Occasionally the machines running Kafka were shutdown. I want to send an email alert if the cluster is not available.

I can create a producer and consumer to send and receive dummy messages periodically. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: @MohamedSweelam Python Kafka

Comment: You could install Datadog/Nagios/Sysdig, etc for full system monitoring rather than _exclusively Kafka_

Answer (score 1):

Actually knowing if cluster is up is not so easy at all, there is discussion with community what is the best practice to decide if kafka cluster is up and active but there is no current good way to get this information,  as kafka architecture is distributed system, you might have big clusters and while one or more brokers are down , still having your cluster to give high available service, not effecting the integrity of data. Also you might have problems with one topic while on other topics it might work fine.

One suggestion I read which might give you the most certain approach is to produce "dummy" msgs to your applicative topics, and "skip" these msgs on consumption,  that guarantee you that your application would work. I don't like this approach very much as it requires to "send junk to your main topics"

Other approaches are like you say "produce/consume  to/from test/healthcheck topic" but it is might not give full guarantee that your application would work, this is a lot like select from dummy in other db approaches... if for them is good enough....

Another suggestion is to use AdminClient to read the metrics of cluster, if metrics are provided that usually means the cluster is healthy , also not very good guarantee...

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
It won't send you emails, but it much easier than send dummy messages

Answer (score 0):

I asked in comment which language are you using, maybe you are using something like spring which has `HealthIndicator` to check component status, but for your case it would be little different.

> First of all, you should know that Kafka by default should be [High
> Available,](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.10/srm-overview/topics/srm-highly-available-arch.html) so while building the cluster you should follow the bold
> lines of best practices, you should ensure that you have replicas of
> machines. This is good assumption that will make you satisfied over implementing all of this.

But, if you want to check health of a cluster, you can use admin process, you can use [AdminClient](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html), with help of some utilities; you can check list of topics, groups, etc that you have. But this not 100% guarantee for you although it is good workaround.

You can do that using as you mentioned periodic scheduler, and send email based on the findings you get. But again this is not the ideal solution, and HA cluster infrastructure should save lots of time for you if you build it correctly from the beginning.